# Changing A ComboBox to a TextBox inside a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

Question in title. Seems like something which should be really simple, but i just cannot find it. I am in Design Mode. See picture below, but it's nothing out of the ordinary, really. Really grateful for any suggestions.

[image]

In case it matters: This is Excel 2010.

Comment: Change it at design time or run time?

Comment: At design time.

Comment: As you've discovered, there is no Change To right click menu item like there is in Access. They use different forms engines. Not that that's an excuse to be missing useful features.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do it?

I don't think you can change type of components. You could place textbox in the same place as combobox and hide/unhide them (change Visible property to true or false) separately.

Comment: Yeah, you can't _change_ the component type. You can only delete the original and replace it with a new one.

Comment: The reason i want to do it because it just no longer used as ComboBox, but what is in it is still being used in the table itself. (The users just entered something freeform). So i just wanted to change it to accomodate.

There is also some code which uses its name to read it out and put in the right place. Thats why i wanted to change and not delete and replace, but i guess there is no other way.

Comment: You can delete it, @wlfbck, replace it with a new component and give the new component the old component's name. Then your existing code will still work, though there are properties and methods of a combo box that aren't applicable to a text box & vice versa. Of course if it's named `cboBox1`, that'll be weird when referencing a text box, but that's just a reason to give good names to things... [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) will help with the renaming. *_User and minor contributor to the OSS project._

Comment: Thanks for the link to Rubberduck and the suggestion, just seems weird to me this doesn't exist since Access apparently has a "change to" option when in design mode for forms.